# Security implications disabling promotion of distributed transaction for linked server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, distributed-transactions

I've a a linked server and I need to run the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO...EXEC linkedserver.sp @parameter
```

Both servers SQL Server 2008R2 SP1. Once I run it I get this error:

> Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 6 The operation could not be
>   performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server
>   "MY.LINKED.SERVER" was unable to begin a distributed
>   transaction.

After searching for the error I saw that lot recommend running:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server = N'[mylinkedserver]',
     @optname = N'remote proc transaction promotion',
     @optvalue = N'false'
```

Is there any security implications on this action I should be aware of?

Other option is to use advanced properties of the linked server object on main server:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do `INSERT INTO...EXEC` locally, sql server will honor it, but when you use Linked server, sql server has to initiate a local transaction and promote / esclate to a distrubuted transaction.

From --> [How to create an autonomous transaction in SQL Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlprogrammability/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008)

> '**remote proc transaction promotion**' is a new option on SQL Server 2008, which allows you to control whether or not you want to enlist remote stored procedure call in a distributed transaction. **When this option is off  (FALSE), the local transaction will not be promoted to distributed transaction.** This is how we are able to separate outer and inner transactions in a "autonomous transaction" fashion.

As far as I am aware, there is no security implication.

Also, refer to [sp_serveroption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms178532%28v=sql.105%29) for more details.